# java method overloading with single argument

Tags: java, overloading

```
public class HelloWorld{
     public static void main(String []args){
        new SampleString().add(null);
     }
}

class SampleString{
    public void add(Object s){
        System.out.println("Inside Object method");
    }
    public void add(String s){
        System.out.println("Inside string method");
    }
}
```

Why does the program print "Inside string method" and not "Inside Object method" ?
Can you please explain me the logic behind this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler picks the most specific implementation based on the type of the argument passed to the method.

From the Java Language Specification [section on determining compile-time method signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5):

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the *most specific* method is chosen.

Comment: I suspect the best section to quote from is actually 15.12.2.5

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the correction. I've been looking for that one.

Comment: Thanks @Neil Locketz manouti. If i have two classes suppose A and B which both extends C. And then i pass add(A a) and add(B b) and then in the main method call add(null). Which one shall be printed ?

Comment: @Sourav You'd get a compiler error due to ambiguity. This is also explained in the provided link.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and the reference link.

Answer (score 0):

It will choose the highest level type that applies. Since String extends Object it becomes the highest level. If you call it with something that isn't a String it should use the Object one

Comment: "Highest level" isn't a very specific term. It would be better if you could use the same terminology as the language specification.